# do rockets follow a straight path but is looks curved because of space time?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime

does path of the rocket or anything going straight up will look curved because the mass of the earth is curving space time

but if we assume the earth, the rocket and all the celestial bodies whose gravitational field reach the  earth to be mass less then the rocket will follow truly a straight line cause there would be nothing curving the space time

Comment: Look at any space shuttle launch video on YouTube. It is clearly seen tilting onto it's "back" (upside down) purely to achieve orbit, by gradually pointing the engines from vertical to a path roughly parallel to the Earth's surface (before the fuel runs out just before orbital insertion.)

Answer (score 0):

A rocket taking off from the surface of the earth follows a curved path because its guidance system is steering it that way, so as to position it properly for entry into orbit or to point it towards its target if its path is suborbital.

Comment: if it is aim at nothing just travelling straight up will it still look curved cause space time is curved due to the mass of the earth

Comment: the mass of the earth is *no way* strong enough to bend light into a path that curved. Black hole = yes, earth = no.